# Edge Existence (to find if an edge exists or not)

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm, graph-theory

Question is:
You have been given an undirected graph consisting of *N* nodes and *M* edges. This graph can consist of self-loops as well as multiple edges. In addition , you have also been given *Q* queries. For each query, you shall be given 2 integers *A* and *B*. You just need to find if there exists an edge between node *A* and node *B*. If yes, print "YES" (without quotes) else , print "NO"(without quotes).

My code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    vector< vector<int> > v;
    int a,b;

    vector<int>temp;

    while(m--)
    {
        cin>>a>>b;
        temp.push_back(a);
        v.push_back(temp);
        v[a].push_back(b);
        temp.clear();
    }

    int q;
    cin>>q;

    while(q--)
    {
    cin>>a>>b;
    int flag=0;

    for(int i=0;i<v[a].size();i++)
    {
        if(v[a][i]==b)
        {
        cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        flag=1;
        break;

        }
    }

    if(flag!=1)
    cout<<"NO"<<endl;

    }


    return 0;
}
```

I am getting *segmentation fault*. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For example when you want to add the edge `(3,5)` you push 3 into an empty vector ( `temp` ) and then you `push_back` temp into `v`. So now size of `v` is 1. Then you try to `push_back` 5 to `v[3]`:

```
v[a].push_back(b);
```

`v[3]` doesn't exist because your `v` only has 1 item. Hence the *segmentation fault*.

*What should I do?*
Because you know the number of the nodes beforehand (`n`) you can initialize your `v` with the number of nodes ( `n+1` if you want to use 1-indexing). So `v` will have `n` empty `vector`s. Then you can safely `push_back` items into `v[a]`. Also because your graph is undirected for every edge *(a,b)* you should do both `v[a].push_back(b)` and `v[b].push_back(a)`.

Here is a working example:

```
int n,m;
cin>>n>>m;
vector< vector<int> > v(n+1); // initialize v with (n+1) empty vectors 
                              // because we want to use 1-indexing
int a,b;
while(m--)
{
    cin>>a>>b;
    v[a].push_back(b);
    v[b].push_back(a);
}
```